# How to make the timer tickle each second and make it jump when video is forwarded or rewinded?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, timer, html5-video

I am trying to make a timer which indirectly syncs with the video. When `starttimer` is clicked, it should starts my timer and tickle each second.

Here is the process:

```
1. Start the video
2. At a certain time in video, click to start the timer
3. Timer starts from 00:00:00 and should tickle each second.
4. If the video is forwarded by `n` seconds timer should be 'timer+n` seconds. Same for the case, when video is rewinded - `timer-n'
```

But my timer, is not functioning properly. It works fine, when I start the timer but when I forward by `n` seconds, it sometimes goes by `n` and sometimes by `n+1` or `n+2` and when I rewind by `n` it goes back at its own will.

I just cannot get the logic correct.

Called when `starttimer` is clicked: (It starts the clock from 00:00:00)

```
 var mtimer = 0;
 $('#starttimer').click(function() { // Starts the clock
                                playing = true;

                                if(!timerstarted) {
                                    setInterval(function() {
                                    if(playing) {                                               
                                            mtimer++;
                                        $('#starttimer').html(getHHMMSS(mtimer));
                                    }
                                        } , 1000 ); 
                                    timerstarted = true;
                                }
                            });
```

When video is forwarded or rewinded: (I also have a control, wherein I could move the video forward by 3 seconds or back by 3 seconds by pressing shift+r and shift+l. I hope it is equivalent to `seeking`)

```
var lastCurrentTime = 0;
$('#match').on('seeking',function(event) {
                                     var difference = 0;
                                     var newCurrentTime = $('#match').get(0).currentTime;
                                    if(newCurrentTime > lastCurrentTime) {
                                        difference = newCurrentTime - lastCurrentTime;
                                            playing = false;
                                            mtimer = mtimer + difference;
                                            $('#starttimer').html(getHHMMSS(mtimer));
                                            playing = true;
                                    }else {
                                        difference = lastCurrentTime - newCurrentTime;

                                            playing = false;
                                            mtimer = mtimer - difference; 
                                            console.log("Difference : " + difference);
                                            playing = true;

                                        if(mtimer <= 0) {
                                            mtimer = 0;
                                            $('#starttimer').html(getHHMMSS(mtimer));
                                        }
                                    }
              lastCurrentTime = newCurrentTime; 

            });
```

Comment: So you want to emit the `timeupdate` event from within a `setInterval`?

Comment: You have to do your plus minus stuff in the handle/callbacks of video forward and backward operation. Otherwise there is not ant best way except setInterval.

Comment: @sunilsharma how will that effect? I am still doing it on `seeking` event

Comment: That is fine, what values are your two variables holed. newCurrentTime, lastCurrentTime  ?? seconds or what ?

Comment: @sunilsharma each hold the seconds.

Comment: I think you getHHMMSS(mtimer)  does not work fine !!

Comment: @sunilsharma what makes you think that? See my answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Set the offfset
2. Use offset for moving mtimer back and forth
3. clearinterval when seeking

`starttimer` function:

```
 $('#starttimer').click(function() { // Starts the clock
                                playing = true;

                                if(!timerstarted) {
                                    offset = $('#match').get(0).currentTime;
                                    timerv = setInterval(function() {
                                        var newCurrentTime = $('#match').get(0).currentTime;


                                    if(playing) {                                               
                                            mtimer++;
                                        $('#starttimer').html(getHHMMSS(mtimer));
                                    }                                                                              

                                            //$('#starttimer').html(getHHMMSS(mtimer));
                                        } , 1000 ); 
                                    timerstarted = true;
                                }
                            });
```

`seeking` function:

```
$('#match').on('seeking',function(event) {
                                    playing = true;
                                    if(timerstarted) {
                                        clearInterval(timerv);
                                        var newCurrentTime = $('#match').get(0).currentTime;
                                        mtimer = newCurrentTime - offset;
                                       if(mtimer < 0) {
                                                   mtimer = 0;  
                                                   offset = 0;
                                                   $('#starttimer').html(getHHMMSS(mtimer));
                                                   console.log("playing : " + playing);
                                       }
                                       timerv = setInterval(function() {                                       
                                           if(playing) { 
                                                   console.log("Inside playing...");
                                                   mtimer++;
                                               $('#starttimer').html(getHHMMSS(mtimer));
                                           }                                                                              
                                               /*if(playing) {
                                                   if(timerset === true && $('#timeentered').val() !== '') {
                                                       mtimer = $('#timeentered').val();
                                                       timerset = false;
                                                   }
                                                  mtimer++;
                                               }*/
                                               //$('#starttimer').html(getHHMMSS(mtimer));
                                           } , 1000 ); 
                                       lastCurrentTime = newCurrentTime;
                                    } 
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to sync your two timer variables when you start the timer. The `mtimer` variable starts counting the seconds when you start the timer, but `lastCurrentTime` is set to zero until the first time you 'seek' the video one direction or another. This is going to throw the timing off.

Let's say you start the timer one minute into the video. Once you have watched the video for a minute, `mtimer` is at 60 seconds, the video timer is at 120 seconds, and `lastCurrentTime` is still at zero. If I roll the video back by 90 seconds, `mtimer` should go negative by thirty seconds, but, based on your code, `mtimer` will be set to positive 30.

Try this:

```
var mtimer = 0;
var lastCurrentTime = 0;
$('#starttimer').click(function() { // Starts the clock
                            playing = true;

                            if(!timerstarted) {

                                //Set the timer before starting the interval
                                //Gives you one second with the timer at zero before the first interval runs
                                $('#starttimer').html(getHHMMSS(mtimer));

                                //Set lastCurrentTime to the video time.
                                lastCurrentTime = $('#match').get(0).currentTime;
                                setInterval(function() {
                                    if(playing) {                                               
                                        //Keeps both timers synched as the movie plays.
                                        mtimer++;
                                        lastCurrentTime++;
                                        $('#starttimer').html(getHHMMSS(mtimer));
                                }
                                    } , 1000 ); 
                                timerstarted = true;
                            }
                        });
```

Now, your current seeking function should work. If the `newCurrentTime` is larger than the `lastCurrentTime`, `mtimer` will be advanced by the difference. If the opposite is true, then `mtimer` will be reduced by the difference. In the case I mentioned above, when `mtimer` should have gone negative by thirty seconds, `mtimer` would be set to zero. Based on your code, I'm assuming you want the timer reset if `mtimer` goes below zero.

Hope this fits your needs.